# Change default library

Tags: r, knitr

Is there a way to change default library in Knitr? I get this error:

```
Loading required package: knitr
Warning message:
In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called 'knitr'
Error: could not find function "knit"
Execution halted
```

I use RStudio and read topic on this problem on rstudio's support but i still have the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I know what should I do. Create file Renviron.site in R/etc and  include line R_LIBS=C:/Program Files/RStudio/R/library. Works well.

Comment: Another solution is to change order of .libPaths(), first should be R Studio library.

Answer (score 0):

What OS?

Do you know about `Rprofile` and `Rprofile.site`?

Have you read `help(Startup)`?

Why does your R installation directory differ from the one use by RStudio?

Comment: Windows 7, what should I do with Rprofile and Rprofile.site? What should I change there?

Comment: You want to set the `.libPaths`, eg via something like `.libPaths(c("c:/opt/R-library", .libPaths()))` -- adjust according to where your library lives.  Then check in R, and RStudio, by calling `libPaths()` to have it tell you its current value.

Comment: There are two default libraries one in R 15.1 folder, second in Rstudio folder: "C:/Program Files/R/R-2.15.1/library" "C:/Program Files/RStudio/R/library".

Comment: I suspect you will have to tell you normal R session about the RStudio one; look in both directories where knitr actually is and then use .libPaths() to make _both_ directories known to _both_ engines.